# Using Adhoc Profile for DriverKit show error: Xcode 14 and later requires a DriverKit development profile enabled for iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipados, driverkit

We got an app for iPad which has two targets one for the App itself (MainApp target ) and another one for the Driver ( Driver Target ) using DriverKit.

The app works fine in Development, but I'm trying to distribute it with adhoc.

I've requested the Distribution Entitlement to Apple, after getting it, the App Id for the Driver has the following Capabilities:

DriverKit, DriverKit (development), DriverKit USB Transport (development), DriverKit USB Transport - VendorID, In-App Purchase

Now in the profile section, I've created a adhoc profile for the Driver AppId (Identifier). Obviously I've also created an Adhoc profile for the Main AppId

Finally in the Signing & Capabilities Section I set up the profiles for MainApp target, int the Debug one I set up the Development one and int the Release one I set up the adhoc one.

I do the same in the Driver Target, but when I set up the Adhoc one in the Release, I've got a warning:

```
Xcode 14 and later requires a DriverKit development profile enabled for iOS and macOS. Visit the developer website to create or download a DriverKit profile.
```

Also interestingly the Signing Certificate section says: None

[image: SigningAndCapabilitiesDriverTarget]

I also set up the Capabilities for the Driver Target:

- DriverKit USB Transport - VendorID
- DriverKit USB Transport ( Development )

Inside these capabilities I set up the vendor ID as dictionary

[image: Idvendor]

The problem is, if I try to Archive the app I will get the previous Warning message as error:

```
Xcode 14 and later requires a DriverKit development profile enabled for iOS and macOS. Visit the developer website to create or download a DriverKit profile.
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: I've run into the same issue with macOS "Developer ID" signing of dexts with Xcode 14/15. I have contacted Apple DTS via a TSI to find out what the supported solution is, but for the moment, I've set the dext to use development signing in Xcode, and then re-sign it via a "run script" build phase in the container app. (Remove existing signature from binary, copy in correct embedded.provisionprofile, perform codesign.)

Comment: OK, Apple got back to me -my understanding of the official solution is to set everything to development signing in the Xcode project. Perform an archive build, and in the Xcode archive organiser UI, go through the deployment assistant flow with the relevant type of certificate. (ad hoc, developer ID, etc.) I still need to try this out myself though.

Comment: Hi @pmdj I think tried this before. It didn't work for me because when I did the archiving it complains with this:
Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

  Embedded Binary Signing Certificate: Apple Development
  Parent App Signing Certificate:  Apple Distribution

Is the same for you?

Comment: I ran into the same error when I did it *incorrectly*. This happens if you don't remove the development signature from the binary first. (`codesign --force` only re-signs the bundle, **not** the executable binary inside it. `--force --deep` would, but that's bad for other reasons.) Apple advises using the Xcode Organiser or `xcodebuild -exportArchive`, but I still need to experiment with that myself before I can make a recommendation.

Comment: I achieved to exported as ipa file following this advise from the Apple Development forum ( I think it's the easiest way ). And it's similar to what you described. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/743021

So basically set all the provisioning profile to development, in the Debug and Release profile. Then XCode Archive function will chose the right profile for you.

We use fastlane to export the app, so lets see how that works :) I will keep you posted any updates

Comment: @pmdj did you get any results. It turns out the solution I had is not good to distribute the app in the Apple Store as I need so sign manually certain files ( such as scripts files copied inside of the app )